# curl in RoR: Status 400 error: Bad Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, curl

Ruby Version: 2.2.4
Rails Version: 5.0.0.1 
System: Windows 7
 Hello People,

I am new on RoR and I follow strict the Token-based authentication with Ruby on Rails 5 API Tutorial ( http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/ruby-ruby-on-rails/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api)
However, when I use the curl command there is an error.

I put in the commandline this while starting rails server (which works):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email":"example@mail.com","password":"123123123"}' http://localhost:3000/authenticate
```

But then this happen:

```
 {"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"#\u003cActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError: 814: unexpected token at ''{email:example@mail.com,password:123123123}''\u003e","
    traces":{"Application Trace":[],"Framework Trace":[{"id":0,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:71:in `rescue in parse_formatted_parameters'"},{"id
    ":1,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:65:in `parse_formatted_parameters'"},{"id":2,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/reques
    t.rb:366:in `block in POST'"},{"id":3,"trace":"rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/request.rb:57:in `fetch'"},{"id":4,"trace":"rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/request.rb:57:in `fetch_header'"},{"id":5,"t
    race":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:365:in `POST'"},{"id":6,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:282:in `_wrappe
    r_enabled?'"},{"id":7,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:231:in `process_action'"},{"id":8,"trace":"activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_reco
    rd/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'"},{"id":9,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'"},{"id":10,"trace":"actionpack (5
    .0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'"},{"id":11,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'"},{"id":12,"trace":"actionpack (
    5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'"},{"id":13,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'"},{"id":14,"trac
    e":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'"},{"id":15,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'"}
    ,{"id":16,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'"},{"id":17,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:i
    n `call'"},{"id":18,"trace":"rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'"},{"id":19,"trace":"rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'"},{"id":20,"trace":"rack (2.0.1)
    lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'"},{"id":21,"trace":"activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'"},{"id":22,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/
    middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'"},{"id":23,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'"},{"id":24,"trace":"activesuppo
    rt (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'"},{"id":25,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'"},{"id"
    :26,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'"},{"id":27,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:i
    n `call'"},{"id":28,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'"},{"id":29,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/
    debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'"},{"id":30,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'"},{"id":31,"trace":"railties (5.0.0.1) lib
    /rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'"},{"id":32,"trace":"railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'"},{"id":33,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active
    _support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'"},{"id":34,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'"},{"id":35,"trace":"activesuppor
    t (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'"},{"id":36,"trace":"railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'"},{"id":37,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.
    1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'"},{"id":38,"trace":"rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'"},{"id":39,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/acti
    ve_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'"},{"id":40,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'"},{"id":41,"trace
    ":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'"},{"id":42,"trace":"rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'"},{"id":43,"trace":"railties (5.
    0.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'"},{"id":44,"trace":"puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'"},{"id":45,"trace":"puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handl
    e_request'"},{"id":46,"trace":"puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'"},{"id":47,"trace":"puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'"},{"id":48,"trace"
    :"puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `call'"},{"id":49,"trace":"puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'"}],"Full Trace":[{"id":0,"trace":"acti
    onpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:71:in `rescue in parse_formatted_parameters'"},{"id":1,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb
    :65:in `parse_formatted_parameters'"},{"id":2,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:366:in `block in POST'"},{"id":3,"trace":"rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/req
    uest.rb:57:in `fetch'"},{"id":4,"trace":"rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/request.rb:57:in `fetch_header'"},{"id":5,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:365:in `
    POST'"},{"id":6,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:282:in `_wrapper_enabled?'"},{"id":7,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controlle
    r/metal/params_wrapper.rb:231:in `process_action'"},{"id":8,"trace":"activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'"},{"id":9,"trac
    e":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'"},{"id":10,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'"},{"id":11,"tra
    ce":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'"},{"id":12,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'"},{"i
    d":13,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'"},{"id":14,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `bl
    ock in serve'"},{"id":15,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'"},{"id":16,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/rout
    er.rb:26:in `serve'"},{"id":17,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'"},{"id":18,"trace":"rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'"
    },{"id":19,"trace":"rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'"},{"id":20,"trace":"rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'"},{"id":21,"trace":"activerecord (5.0.0.1)
     lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'"},{"id":22,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'"},{"id":23,"trace":"active
    support (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'"},{"id":24,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks
    '"},{"id":25,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'"},{"id":26,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbac
    ks.rb:36:in `call'"},{"id":27,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'"},{"id":28,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/mi
    ddleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'"},{"id":29,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'"},{"id":30,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1
    ) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'"},{"id":31,"trace":"railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'"},{"id":32,"trace":"railties (5.0
    .0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'"},{"id":33,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'"},{"id":34,"trace":"a
    ctivesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'"},{"id":35,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'"},{"id":
    36,"trace":"railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'"},{"id":37,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'"},{"id":38,
    "trace":"rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'"},{"id":39,"trace":"activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'"},{"id"
    :40,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'"},{"id":41,"trace":"actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in
    `call'"},{"id":42,"trace":"rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'"},{"id":43,"trace":"railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'"},{"id":44,"trace":"puma (3.6.0
    ) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'"},{"id":45,"trace":"puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'"},{"id":46,"trace":"puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `p
    rocess_client'"},{"id":47,"trace":"puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'"},{"id":48,"trace":"puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `call'"},{"id":49,"trace":
    "puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'"}]}}
```

UPDATE: if I use this curl command I can connect:

```
 curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST  http://localhost:3000/authenticate -d "{\"email\":\"example@mail.com\",\"password\":\"123123123\"}"
```

But then I get this error:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Could not resolve host: application
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Could not resolve host: application
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#2)
> POST /authenticate HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.50.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 51
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 51 out of 51 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< X-Request-Id: 0c6cd1b4-0482-4536-9395-106f5dd2bf5f
< X-Runtime: 0.017592
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
{"error":{"user_authentication":["invalid credentials"]}}* Connection #2 to host localhost left intact
```

Does somebody knows what I did wrong?

Here is my code:

## app/commands/authenticate_user.rb

```
class AuthenticateUser
  prepend SimpleCommand

  def initialize(email, password)
    @email = email
    @password = password
  end

  def call
    JsonWebToken.encode(user_id: user.id) if user
  end

  private

  attr_accessor :email, :password

  def user
    user = User.find_by_email(email)
    return user if user && user.authenticate(password)

    errors.add :user_authentication, 'invalid credentials'
    nil
  end
end
```

## app commands authorize_api_request.rb

```
class AuthorizeApiRequest
  prepend SimpleCommand

  def initialize(headers = {})
    @headers = headers
  end

  def call
    user
  end

  private

  attr_reader :headers

  def user
    @user ||= User.find(decoded_auth_token[:user_id]) if decoded_auth_token
    @user || errors.add(:token, 'Invalid token') && nil
  end

  def decoded_auth_token
    @decoded_auth_token ||= JsonWebToken.decode(http_auth_header)
  end

  def http_auth_header
    if headers['Authorization'].present?
      return headers['Authorization'].split(' ').last
    else
      errors.add(:token, 'Missing token')
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

In controllers I have following 3 controller: 1. application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_action :authenticate_request
  attr_reader :current_user

  private

  def authenticate_request
    @current_user = AuthorizeApiRequest.call(request.headers).result
    render json: { error: 'Not Authorized' }, status: 401 unless @current_user
  end
end
```

authentication-controller.rb

```
class AuthenticationController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_request

  def authenticate
    command = AuthenticateUser.call(params[:email], params[:password])

    if command.success?
      render json: { auth_token: command.result }
    else
      render json: { error: command.errors }, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end
end
```

items_controller.rb

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /items
  def index
    @items = Item.all

    render json: @items
  end

  # GET /items/1
  def show
    render json: @item
  end

  # POST /items
  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)

    if @item.save
      render json: @item, status: :created, location: @item
    else
      render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /items/1
  def update
    if @item.update(item_params)
      render json: @item
    else
      render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /items/1
  def destroy
    @item.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_item
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description)
    end
end
```

Then i have routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :items
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  post 'authenticate', to: 'authentication#authenticate'
end
```

Comment: Can you try to escape double quotes in  the curl call and report back if this works? Like this: `'{\"email\":\"example@mail.com\",\"password\":\"123123123\"}'`

Comment: If I put this: curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST  http://localhost:3000/authenticate -d "{\"email\":\"example@mail.com\",\"password\":\"123123123\"}"  I still get error: user_authentication invalid credentials

Comment: If I use your recommended curl call: 
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{\"email\":\"example@mail.com\",\"password\":\"123123123\"}‌​' http://localhost:3000/authenticate     I get still 400 error Bad Request. Has somebody an idea why I get error with curl? I followed strictly the tutorial..